# Have letters slide along pane then fall into a bucket

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'd like to create an animation where several words moves along an edge (hard surface).  When the letters get to the end of the edge, each letter then falls into a containers.  The container then shakes and outputs a new word.

I can make the individual letters move along the edge, but when I apply gravity "Active" in the Physics section, it behaves not as expected.

Any samples out there I can review?

Thank you,

Comment: please explain "not as expected". I recommend downloading "GifCam" to record short footage of Blender.

Comment: Hello Hatinacat2000, I want the letters to slide (x1 -> x2) along an axis.  If I enable "active" in physics the letters fall down (flat on the surface).  If I set mass to 0.01 the letters float away.  I tried two different letters: one to move them with the location setting and the other with gravity.  However, when I try to place the letter with the gravity to its starting point in frame 60, it ignores its position.  I need zero gravity until frame 60 for the first letter, then frame 65 for the second, etc.  I am unable to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Hi, Mike. I think you should upload your .blend file with the animation frames that aren't working out. Google "Blend Exchange" and update your question with the link it generates for you.